# Magento2 Application Automation Testing - For Automation Testers

Tags: magento2, testing, automation, selenium

I am doing automation testing on **Magento2 application** for one of my client.

I have heard from some people there are some automated testing frameworks for Magento 2. But everything seems to be helpful for developers for performing unit test only. I am automating the application using Selenium WebDriver, **TestNG and JAVA**, and it is working fine. I would like to know is there any other tools or technology stack for testers to do automation testing which covers all test cases and workflows.

So I would like to get more insights on this, if you have worked on Magento 2 automation testing, please help me!

Things I would like to know:

1. Whether it is a good practice to automate Magneto2 application with Selenium WebDriver+TestNG+Java?
2. Is there any specific tool for Magento 2 Application testing for testers, not for unit testing/functional testing for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides his own tool for automation testing called MFTF(Magento Functional Testing Framework). 
More detailed information how to use it you can find on the official DevDocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/2.3/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I heard that MFTF is mostly uaed for unit testing. I never tried using it but had donr R&D on this. Please correct me if im wrong. Also, please advise on using selenium webdriver is good attempt or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too have the same doubt from where to start the automation test for Magento2 framework?
Also, the below-mentioned URL doesn't work
https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/2.3/introduction.html
Can anyone resolve from where and how to start automation testing for the Magento project?

Comment: As a QA perspective, it's better to try using selenium webdriver and testng framework. Recently I have automated magento 2 application for one of our client using selenium, java and testng and it was a success. It was a multi vendor market place and I have automated all regression scenarios like manage vendors, manage customers, shipping module etc.    If you are comfortable with test scripts better go for selenium webdriver.

Comment: If you don't mind can you invite me for a personal chat since I have a doubt regarding testing